# Android ListView String Styles

Tags: android, listview

I am wanting to know if I can add some style to strings used in a list view?  I have tried html formatting using escape codes and all I seem to get are the codes displayed but not actually doing what I desire.  I would like to have the strings in the LISTVIEW to be bold then newline not bold and if possible a smaller size font.  I currently have BOLD codes but that does not seem to do anything either and it does not give me any format errors.

```
ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);
String[] items = 
{ 
   getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_one),
   getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_two),
   getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_three),
   getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_four),
   getResources().getString(R.string.menu_item_five),
   getResources().getString(R.string.menu_method_six), 
 };
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, 
   R.layout.menu_item, items);
 menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
```

The strings look like this

```
<string name="menu_item_one"><b>This should be BOLD</b>\nSshould should not be be bold and smaller font if possible</string>
<string name="menu_item_two"><b>This should be BOLD</b>\nSshould should not be be bold and smaller font if possible</string>
<string name="menu_item_three"><b>This should be BOLD</b>\nSshould should not be be bold and smaller font if possible</string>
<string name="menu_item_four"><b>This should be BOLD</b>\nSshould should not be be bold and smaller font if possible</string>
<string name="menu_item_five"><b>This should be BOLD</b>\nSshould should not be be bold and smaller font if possible</string>
<string name="menu_item_six"><b>This should be BOLD</b>\nSshould should not be be bold and smaller font if possible</string>
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT WHEN ASKING YOUR QUESTIONS. It makes them harder to read, and won't get you answers any faster. It also is extremely annoying, and means that someone has to edit your post to remove them. Also, please use the preview that appears below your question when you're posting it to check things like code formatting. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `getResources().getText()` instead, and let your other variables be a `CharSequence[]` and `ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>`.  This should preserve the formatting you have in your XML declaration all the way through to the point where the text is set on the view in each list item.

For clarity, I have rewritten your code sample in this fashion:

```
ListView menuList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView_Menu);
CharSequence[] items = 
{ 
   getResources().getText(R.string.menu_item_one),
   getResources().getText(R.string.menu_item_two),
   getResources().getText(R.string.menu_item_three),
   getResources().getText(R.string.menu_item_four),
   getResources().getText(R.string.menu_item_five),
   getResources().getText(R.string.menu_item_six), 
};
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapt = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, R.layout.menu_item, items);
menuList.setAdapter(adapt);
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Not sure where CharSequence[] goes. I would appreciate a little guidance.  TIA

Comment: I have rewritten your sample with the proper modifications, and removed my other suggestion as I have tested this code and it works.